# Running an inline multiline powershell script from a Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: powershell, jenkins

I am having a hard time figuring out the correct groovy syntax for Jenkins Powershell.
Here is what my stage is looking like:

```
stage('Cleanup') {
        steps {
            powerShell('''$serv_status = get-service myService

                if($serv_status -ne $null)
                { 
                    "Old version of myService detected"
                    "Stopping the service..."
                    net stop myService
                    
                    "Removing the service..."
                    sc.exe delete myService
                }''')
               
            
            dir ("${env.ROOT_PATH}")
            {
                cleanWs()
            }
        }
    }
```

Instead of using quotes I have also tried to print using Write-Output this way, but without success:

```
Write-Output '"Old version of myService  detected"'
```

Any tip on how to get this working would be appreciated

Comment: The multiline string literal looks correct, but `powerShell` is incorrect syntax. It has to be all lower-case `powershell`.

Comment: @zett42, that did the trick, duh! Thanks a lot.